# mu4e does not retrieve emails from remote email server

Tags: spacemacs, mu4e

I currently have my mu4e setup and working properly, except for one thing. Using the "U" key in mu4e in emacs does not seem to retrieve the emails using `mbsync`. I am using spacemacs (in case that is relavent).

This is my emacs configuration:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq mu4e-reply-to-address "my.email@website.com")
  (setq mu4e-get-mail-command "mbsync -a")
)
```

The interesting part is that when using the "U" keybinding, mu4e *does* index my new emails, but it does not retrieve them, despite having set the `mbsync` command above.

It should be noted that when I run `mbsync` manually from my terminal I am able to retrieve the new emails successfully (I first send an email from another account, run `mbsync` from terminal, then index from mu4e, and all is well), so my wager is that something is incorrectly configured within mu4e itself, and not `mbsync`. I will also note that my mail directory is set at `~/Maildir/` within my mbsyncrc configuration file.

What steps could I take to retrieve emails using the mu4e "U" keybinding using mbsync?

Comment: AFAIK mu can't index messages that were not downloaded. How can you tell they were not retrieved?

Comment: @YoungFrog, I can tell that the messages are not retrieved from mu4e because I run the "U" keybinding (which indicates no new messages in my inbox) then I proceed to run mbsync manually from the terminal using `mbsync -a`, which then indicates a new message received (in this case a test message sent from another email account).

The question has been edited for clarity.

Comment: C-h v mu4e-get-mail-command
(describe-variable) To ensure the command is set correctly.

Comment: Does `(executable-find "mbsync")` locate that program?  If not, check `C-h v exec-path`, or use the absolute path in the mu4e config.